# How to fix console.error: "This browser lacks typed array (Uint8Array) support which is required by buffer v5.x. Use buffer v4.x if ..."

Tags: react-native

Suddenly this `buffer` problem came up within our project. It's quite strange from where it comes...

console.error: "**This browser lacks typed array (Uint8Array) support which is required by `buffer` v5.x. Use `buffer` v4.x if you require old browser support.**"

```
console.error: "This browser lacks typed array (Uint8Array) 
support which is required by `buffer` v5.x. 
Use `buffer` v4.x if you require old browser support."
<unknown>
    index.js:41:4
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:321:6
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:207:36
metroRequire
    require.js:127:24
<unknown>
    scclientsocket.js:9:20
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:321:6
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:207:36
metroRequire
    require.js:127:24
<unknown>
    index.js:1:28
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:321:6
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:207:36
metroRequire
    require.js:127:24
<unknown>
    devTools.js:15:34
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:321:6
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:207:36
metroRequire
    require.js:127:24
<unknown>
    index.js:6:23
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:321:6
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:207:36
metroRequire
    require.js:127:24
<unknown>
    store.js:10
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:321:6
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:207:36
metroRequire
    require.js:127:24
<unknown>
    HomeScreen.js:9
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:321:6
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:207:36
metroRequire
    require.js:127:24
<unknown>
    index.js:3
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:321:6
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:199:45
metroRequire
    require.js:127:24
global code
```

`$ react-native info`

```
React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.5
      CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4278U CPU @ 2.60GHz
      Memory: 30.05 MB / 8.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 10.15.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.15.2 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.4.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      Android SDK:
        API Levels: 28
        Build Tools: 28.0.3
        System Images: android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.4 AI-183.6156.11.34.5692245
      Xcode: /undefined - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.5.0 => 16.5.0 
      react-native: 0.58.6 => 0.58.6 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
      react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7
```

Changing to older git branches and version keep giving this issue on emulators and physical devices. We included different buffer versions.

- Although buffer is used by various dependencies we tried: `yarn add buffer@4.9.1`
- We tried `rm -rf node_modules && rm yarn.lock && yarn` within branches that worked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was required to upgrade react-native to a more recent version. Then this error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will be very useful for you but I got the same problem and the only way to have my work environment ready was by starting the Remote JS debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version installed before changing to new

Try to install the `buffer` version 4.

You can use the following command:

```
npm install buffer@4 --save
```